# how to render pdf inside a div for iPad/iPhone?

Tags: html, dojo

I have a PhoneGap - dojo application. I want to render a pdf file inside my app. I used -

```
<div> 
      <object data="CodingGuidelines.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="800"> alt :
          <a href="CodingGuidelines.pdf">pdf
          </a> 
      </object> 
</div>
```

But, this does not render well on iPad. Is there a dojo controll to render a pdf ?
Or, Can we render it using HTML5 ?

Comment: `does not render well`? what do you mean?

Comment: It renders inside width="600" height="800", but if the size of pdf is more or for multiple page pdf, it does not scroll. No pinch and zoom.